# custom animation turns elements opacity to 0 , but can psedo elements opacity be kept to 1

Tags: css, css-animations

i am designing a custom animated button and needed to use a combination of simple CSS-3 transitions and psedo elements .

now i am aware of the fact that pseudo elements are affected by declarations to the element to which they are attached . but i have a contextual question with a difficulty i am having.

**background :**

now i have a custome animation that turn an elements opacity to 0 , however i would like it if the psedo element and its properties can be preserved visually without thier opacity being changed to 0 .

here's a fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcmeejby/)

see how along with the span element being turned to opacity:0 the psedo element too gets its opcaty turned to 0.

BTW , the custome animation is as follows :

```
@-moz-keyframes hidden {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100px);
    }

}
```

and the code that fires the custom animation is as follows :

```
.btn:hover span{
    animation-name:hidden;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;      
}
```

I know if i choose to go without the psedo element there would be a solution , but i'd really like to keep the psedo element in the code .

Thanks .

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by transitioning `rgba(Red, Greeb, Blue, Alpha)` instead of the `opacity`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .3s;
}
.btn {
  outline: 0;
  /*padding: 20px 0;*/
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  color: rgba(101, 141, 102, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.btn:hover span {
  left: -100%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0);
  color: rgba(101, 141, 102, 0);
}
.btn span:after {
  background: red;
  content: 'new content';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn:hover span:after {
  color: rgba(101, 141, 102, 1);
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <span>Hey press me</span> 
</button>
```

Comment: i'll try this out ! thanks , BTW , great Job on the CSS arrow thingi :)